# Suggestions for a thin contact sensor to check if there is contact between two surfaces

Tags: sensor, embedded, proximity-sensor

I am doing a little experiment with my bagpack, making it into a smart bag by adding a contact sensor to pockets such that is any item is inserted the contact between surfaces break and vice versa. I was thinking to simply use 2 metal strips with magnets behind them so that if something is inserted, the circuit breaks but I am a little worried about the exposed end of the circuit (+5V). If I keep something that is sensitive to even small voltages, the exposed 5V surface might damage it. Also if I keep something conductive, it will not work. I was also planning to use a proximity sensor but I am not sure if they are durable/ thin enough to be disguised into a pocket's surface.

Comment: IR diode + phototransistor?

Comment: Most of them are like a button and come out of the thin pocket surface. Also not sure if they are durable.

Comment: Also do not neglect that magnets can damage many objects, electronic or things like your magnetic ID or bank cards.

Comment: Cool idea.  I don't see an advantage to it, but I'll think about it a bit.  Measure stress or strain? conductive fabric and elastics?  I think there's a chance that would work.  Stretch the elastic and sew it to a strip of conductive fabric or put it inside a tube of such while stretched.  The resistance of the fabric strip should decrease as the elastic compresses it.  What kind of rigidity are you hoping for?

Comment: Note that if you use an IR diode and phototransistor as @Lundin suggests, you don't have to have the photodiode always on, you can flash it 1/1000th or so of the time and make your measurement then.  If you're embedding metal strips or using conductive fabric, remember that metal devices will connect things as well.

Comment: Put a magnetic latch on the pockets (this is a thing for handbags purses etc - from leatherwork supplies), and use a hall effect to detect open. Some of the hall effect switches are internally strobed and only draw uA

Comment: Use velcro and a microphone. Just try opening velcro silently.

Comment: You magnet+plate idea does not need galvanic contact. If it has a thin insulating layer (kapton tape), and a big contact area (2" half circles), there is plenty of capacitance, and a high frequency will couple across easily, making it trivial to detect with a micro port pin. You could also have two plates on one side of the pocket (or rivets), and a big overlapping plate on the other side. Make the plates from carbon fibre fabric sewn in.

Comment: If you measure weight in the pocket, that will probably work better than anything, and if you combine that with a few other sensors you can probably get near 100% accuracy.  Speaking of velcro, if you wanted general tamper protection, you could probably easily sense the sound of velcro, although it wouldn't be too hard to generate a false positive.